# Use excel sheet to populate HTML inputs

Tags: python, html, excel, vba

I have a task at work that requires entering the same information every week into a webpage and submitting that information. I am trying to figure out how to automated this process, preferably by taking the text from an excel sheet and populating the webpage inputs.

How should I approach this problem? I'd like to use python if possible, as it's the language I am most familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the text using [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) and produce your web page(s) with the framework of your choice or a simple template.

If you are simply filling in an existing web page you can then use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to open the page and submit the data.

Comment: It seems he needs to fill Html for with the data,  not to make a webpage with it.

Comment: Thanks @Trimax added Mechanize to the answer.

Comment: There is another module to do this that supports Python3?

Comment: xlrd is documented as working on python 3, there is experimental Python 3 branch of mechanize - https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3 but I am not sure of the current status.